# Check if all radio buttons are selected. Using cucumber with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara

I am using Cucumber with Capybara. I have a page with listing of questions for a candidate. I want to check if all the radio buttons are selected for every answer before a candidate hits a radio button. If a candidate hits next button before answering all the questions, an error message is shown.

Please help me how do I test this feature.

Comment: Can you please share some of the html of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have added Cucumber tag, this is how I would write my feature file.

```
Given Im in the question answer page
When I click next without answering all questions
Then I get an error message
When I click next after answering all questions
Then I go to the next page successfully.
```

SInce you have asked how to test, the logic to test is pretty simple

```
Click next without checking any radio box
Look for error message
Click next repeatedly after checking every box one till last but one
Look for error message
Click next after checking all radio boxes
No error message is seen.
```